# Apply the IntegrateChangeVariables function correctly

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Please help me apply the IntegrateChangeVariables function correctly for my case. I need to change the integration variable from Tau to b(t). * in the photo corresponds to Begin in WM. Photo 3 shows the calculations I want to do in WM.

[image]

[image]

```
VSol[\[Rho]_, t_] = (
  b[t]^2*(a^2 - \[Rho]^2)*SigmaPhiBegin[b[t]]*D[b[t], t]/b[t])/(
  2*G*(a^2 + b[t]^2*kappa)*\[Rho]);

(b[t]^2*(a^2 - \[Rho]^2)*SigmaPhiBegin[b[t]]*D[b[t], t]/b[t])/(
 2*G*(a^2 + b[t]^2*kappa)*\[Rho]) // TraditionalForm
DVSol[\[Rho]_, t_] = D[VSol[\[Rho], t], \[Rho]] // FullSimplify;

D[VSol[\[Rho], t], \[Rho]] // FullSimplify // TraditionalForm

DotSigmaRho = G*((kappa + 1) EpsilonRho + (kappa - 1) EpsilonPhi);

DotSigmaPhi = 
  DotSigmaRho /. {EpsilonRho -> EpsilonPhi, 
    EpsilonPhi -> EpsilonRho};

EpsilonRho = D[v[\[Rho], t], \[Rho]];

EpsilonPhi = v[\[Rho], t]/\[Rho];

DVSol = D[VSol[\[Rho], t], \[Rho]];

DotSigmaRhoNew[\[Rho]_, t_] = 
  DotSigmaRho /. v[\[Rho], t] -> VSol[\[Rho], t] /. 
    D[v[\[Rho], t], \[Rho]] -> DVSol // FullSimplify;

DotSigmaRho /. v[\[Rho], t] -> VSol[\[Rho], t] /. 
   D[v[\[Rho], t], \[Rho]] -> DVSol // FullSimplify // TraditionalForm

DotSigmaPhiNew[\[Rho]_, t_] = 
  DotSigmaPhi /. v[\[Rho], t] -> VSol[\[Rho], t] /. 
    D[v[\[Rho], t], \[Rho]] -> DVSol // FullSimplify;

DotSigmaPhi /. v[\[Rho], t] -> VSol[\[Rho], t] /. 
   D[v[\[Rho], t], \[Rho]] -> DVSol // FullSimplify // TraditionalForm

SigmaRho = 
  SigmaRho[\[Rho], \[Tau]Begin[\[Rho]]] + 
     Integrate[
      DotSigmaRhoNew[\[Rho], \[Tau]], {\[Tau], \[Tau]Begin[\[Rho]], 
       t}] /. SigmaRho[\[Rho], \[Tau]Begin[\[Rho]]] -> 0 // 
   FullSimplify;

SigmaRho[\[Rho], \[Tau]Begin[\[Rho]]] + 
    Integrate[
     DotSigmaRhoNew[\[Rho], \[Tau]], {\[Tau], \[Tau]Begin[\[Rho]], 
      t}] /. SigmaRho[\[Rho], \[Tau]Begin[\[Rho]]] -> 0 // 
  FullSimplify // TraditionalForm

SigmaRhoNew = 
  SigmaRho /. t -> b[t] /. b[\[Tau]] -> s /. 
      D[b[\[Tau]], \[Tau]] -> 1/
       D[\[Tau]Begin[s], s] /. \[Tau]Begin[\[Rho]] -> 
      b[\[Tau]Begin[\[Rho]]] /. \[Tau] -> \[Tau]Begin[s] /. 
   b[\[Tau]Begin[\[Rho]]] -> \[Rho];

SigmaRho /. t -> b[t] /. b[\[Tau]] -> s /. 
     D[b[\[Tau]], \[Tau]] -> 1/
      D[\[Tau]Begin[s], s] /. \[Tau]Begin[\[Rho]] -> 
     b[\[Tau]Begin[\[Rho]]] /. \[Tau] -> \[Tau]Begin[s] /. 
  b[\[Tau]Begin[\[Rho]]] -> \[Rho] // TraditionalForm
```

I made edits to assignment 11/30.

Comment: One problem is that in boundary2, b has no time dependence. You plug it into DSolve, with time as a variable, and generate an expression for 'b'. Inside VSol, you then retype the solution modifying b to b[t]. But b either does or doesn't depend on t. You can't have ti both ways. Also, you have tow b's inside VSol, and only one is modified to b[t].  This may not be your only problem, but it alone makes the subsequent steps very questionable.

Comment: jdp, I slightly corrected the code: I corrected semantic errors in solving the problem and removed the initial substitution of variables. Unfortunately, I still need to somehow implement it in the integral. I realized that you cannot change a variable to a function (and vice versa, thanks for the clarification). Please offer ideas on how to implement this, even if it’s very crooked. Or is there no way to do this at all?

Comment: A general change is difficult to produce. For example, `IntegrateChangeVariables[Inactive[Integrate][g[x], {x, a, b}], t, 
 t == f[ x]]` performs "FunctionDomain::nmet: Unable to find the domain with the available methods" and returns the input.

Comment: There's no guarantee of a solution, but it might help if you were to provide a bit more context. The blackboard image isn't too useful, but the equations you posted are. Is that the whole extent of your question though? How to get from the first integral to the third? Because most of your code seems related to the derivation of the terms within the integral. If you're asking for help with that fine, but if so, it would help to understand what's going on. I can recommend using SetDelayed (:=) instead of Set (=) when using patterns. You seem to run DSolve, then manually edit the result,

Comment: ...which risks introducing errors, as per my earlier comment, but other than things like that, it's difficult to offer much advice. Maybe put in a brief explanation of what the equations represent, what the symbols mean, where you're starting point is, what you goal is. You can also use Latex to imbed equations in your question versus posting images if you like. Or should we ignore everything but the last few lines of your posted code?

Comment: I got rid of replacing variable with function, function with variable. But this, unfortunately, did not help. For convenience, I am attaching a link to my code. Please tell me what to fix next?

Public Link
https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/7c929422-7339-45e5-ae66-6af231de6f2f

Authenticated Link
https://www.wolframcloud.com/env/7c929422-7339-45e5-ae66-6af231de6f2f